# Databricks/Spark error on sql Merge Statement. Just says "You have encountered a bug, report it"

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, databricks

I have made some steps on databricks and I hit a strange error where it says a bug has been reached and I should report it. Nothing more comes out, except for the stack trace

So, this is what I was trying to do: I have an AWS RDS (postgres) table, where I intend to upsert rows into it from a data source. My data source is an API i reach to by using python `requests` library on a GET method.

So I fetch the api, receive the response json, convert it to a spark pyspark dataframe, save it as a temporary view (to use sql on it), and then I use my MERGE statement into the RDS table. In hopes of doing an UPSERT from the API (source) to the RDS table.

A tricky part in that, is that the way I reference my RDS table in the MERGE statement. I had to previously create a JDBC connected table in databricks to reference it.

So these were my steps:

1. Create the sql statement using JDBC to make databricks reference my RDS table
2. Call the api and receive the response's json
3. Put the json in a pyspark dataframe (no strange data types here, just strings/integers, no nested data of any type results for any column)
4. On that pyspark dataframe, call `CreateOrReplaceView('staging_data')`
5. Now using a sql cell, I do my MERGE statement, and this is where I hit the bug `Error in SQL statement: SparkException: [INTERNAL_ERROR] The Spark SQL phase planning failed with an internal error. You hit a bug in Spark or the Spark plugins you use. Please, report this bug to the corresponding communities or vendors, and provide the full stack trace.`

The stack trace is at the bottom, but here I share my steps

For step 1, I did this:

```
%sql
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW test
USING JDBC
OPTIONS (
  url '<my_jdbc_string>',
  dbtable 'some_schema.some_table'
  user '<my_user>',
  password '<my_password>'
)
```

I confirmed it worked by later running `%sql SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 10` and it worked

For step 2, its pretty specific for my use case and the API I need, but it's just a standard `response=requests.get(headers,url,paylaod)`

For step 3. this was the code to create the pyspark dataframe (Note, the variable response is the API's json payload which I loaded as a python dictionary):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(response['ID'],int(response['clientID']),float(response['amount']))],
    schema=StructType(fields=[
    StructField('ID',IntegerType()),
    StructField('clientID',IntegerType()),
    StructField('loanAmount',FloatType())
])
    )
```

Then for step 4.
`df.createOrReplaceTempView('staging_test')`
I confirm it works by running `%sql SELECT * FROM staging_test` It returns only 1 row in this case (which is correct from what the API gave me)

Then for step 5:

```
%sql
MERGE INTO test whs
USING (SELECT ID as loan_id,clientID as account_id,amount as amount FROM staging_test) staging
ON whs.loan_id=staging.loan_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET whs.amount=staging.amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (loan_id,account_id,amount)
  VALUES (staging.loan_id,staging.account_id,staging.amount)
```

And that's where I get the bellow error, along with the stacktrace.

All this happend on databricks using a single-node, single-user m6i.large AWS EC2, running this version `13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)` whithout photon accelerator. And the RDS is also in the same AWS account where this databricks is hosted. It's on a different region and different VPC (but I already took care that databrick's ec2 VPC can reach the RDS region and VPC). Additionally, the rds database is postgresql on this instance size `db.m5.large` and with psql engine version 11.19

```
Error in SQL statement: SparkException: [INTERNAL_ERROR] The Spark SQL phase planning failed with an internal error. You hit a bug in Spark or the Spark plugins you use. Please, report this bug to the corresponding communities or vendors, and provide the full stack trace.
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.SparkDriverExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: [INTERNAL_ERROR] The Spark SQL phase planning failed with an internal error. You hit a bug in Spark or the Spark plugins you use. Please, report this bug to the corresponding communities or vendors, and provide the full stack trace.
    at org.apache.spark.SparkException$.internalError(SparkException.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.toInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:937)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.util.LexicalThreadLocal$Handle.runWith(LexicalThreadLocal.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.simpleString(QueryExecution.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainStringLocal(QueryExecution.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:498)
```